# Conversor de precios. ¿Cómo guardar los precios, luego de ser convertidos?

Tags: python, django

Estoy creando un pequeño sistema que muestre artículos con sus diferentes campos con Django.
Mi problema es que no se como hacer que los precios en Cop y BS se guarde a través de una conversión, esta conversión se hace a través del precio en  dólares. Ya tengo la fórmula y ya hice que convirtiera todos los productos, pero no se como hacer para guardarlos en la DB.

El siguiente código es el que hace la conversión de dólar a peso y de dólar a bolívar.

```
def conversor_usd_cop(request):
  template_name = 'price_usd_cop.html'
  products_prices = Product.objects.all()

for product_price in products_prices:
  product_price_in_usd = product_price.product_price_usd

  usd_price_in_cop_day = 3450
  precio_producto_cop = usd_price_in_cop_day * product_price_in_usd
  print(f'USD: {product_price_in_usd}, COP {precio_producto_cop}')


return render(request, template_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que estar haciendo algo asi:

```
def conversor_usd_cop(...):
   for product_price in Product.objects.all():
      product_price.product_price_usd = <el valor en dolares>
      product_price.product_price_cop = <el valor en cop>
      product_price.save()
   return <el return>
```

- La asignacion al parametro dentro del modelo de los valores que estas modificando
- Estar guardando el objeto que se ha modificado